# How not to have browser history linked with image clicks using Ad Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site for car classifieds. I searched for an image gallery to display images that users upload for their submissions and found a simple jQuery based gallery called Ad Gallery, which can be found [here](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/).

I love the simplicity of the gallery and how compatible it is with most browsers including older IE versions. I also love being able to browse images using right and left arrow keys. Also a nice feature is how it automatically scales wide and tall images to fit the container. These are key features for me.

Here is the problem: clicking each thumbnail, or hitting the arrow key to browse images, counts as a new URL and makes the browser save it in the history. So when the user wants to go back to the main page with submissions, they have to cycle through all the images in a reverse order of how they browsed them. This is a huge inconvenience, especially if they are trying to go back to their search results. I cannot find anything that fixes this in the documentation of the plugin. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a parameter for that : "update_window_hash"

Try that :

```
$('#myGallery').adGallery({update_window_hash: false});
```

Not sure at all. Otherwise It seems unsupported.

Comment: This worked after a few tries to optimize for my code. You don't know how happy you made me. Thank you so much.